# Unit testing synchronization

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, synchronization

Consider the following method:

```
/**
 * Set whether messages are printed to System.out.     * 
 * @param printOutput True to print, false for silent logging
 */
public void setPrintOutput(boolean printOutput) {
   // Synchronize to messages because this field is used when a message is received
   synchronized (messages) {
      this.printOutput = printOutput;
   }
}
```

This method is part of a set of several methods that involve `messages`, so I want to write a test that checks that this method is synchronized on `messages`.  Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: The code "synchronized(messages)" causes this to be synchronized on the variable "messages".  This is part of the language and does not need to be unit tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is beyond unit testing because the whole point of synchronization is to provide a certain type of connection between two distant pieces of code.

You can test the way it behaves with `messages` being null and not null, and that gives you full coverage. It won't say anything about whether your synchronization is semantically correct.

Comment: So in that case, this really devolves to a trivial method, then?

Comment: @Michael Pretty much so. Unit testing has its limitations, this is one of them. Proving the correctness of a synchronization scheme isn't impossible but is beyond unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to unit test it then expose the `message` to the test code, get it's lock in one thread and check that you cannot aquire it from another thread (with timeout preventing deadlock). As @biziclop notices you should not test that. You can measure throughput, responsiveness but testing that some particular intrinsic lock is taken is too detailed.